# using string variable from one class in another

Tags: iphone

Rookie question:  I am writing a program that will generate a specific string and then display it in a text window in a different view controller.  I have been testing to ensure that the code in fact generates the string using NSLog commands and I know the code is working as intended.  For some reason it is not transferring across the view controller and I cant figure out why.  Any help?  Here is a snippet of the code:

CreateStoryViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)makeStory:(id)sender 
    {
    StoryLine *myStory =[[StoryLine alloc] init];

    [myStory setStory];
        self.story = myStory.plot;
        NSLog(@"story is %@", self.story);//this is generating the correct story string


    self.displayStoryController = [[BIDDisplayStoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayStoryView" bundle:nil];

    [self.view insertSubview:self.displayStoryController.view atIndex:1];



    }
```

DisplayStoryViewController.m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    BIDCreateStoryViewController *newStory = [[BIDCreateStoryViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"newStory.story is %@",newStory.story);//this generates null message
    self.storyDisplay.text = newStory.story;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong. You're instantiating a new `BIDCreateViewController` object inside your second view controller. This is not the same as the original `BIDCreateViewController` object that pushed your second `BIDDisplayStoryViewController`.

You need to declare a string property in your `BIDDisplayStoryViewController`'s header file.

Something like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain /*or strong, if using ARC*/) NSString *storyToDisplay;
```

Be sure to synthesize this in your implementation file as well.

When you create BIDDisplayStoryViewController inside your first view controller, you need to do it as follows:

```
self.displayStoryController = [[BIDDisplayStoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayStoryView" bundle:nil];
self.displayStoryViewController.storyToDisplay = self.story;
```

Now inside your second view controller you can access this using `self.myStory`.

While this will solve your problem (and please do understand that it's not my intention to be rude here), I feel that there's a lack of understanding of how iOS (and OOP in general) works.

Answer (score 1):

In your viewDidLoad method you are making a whole new story. This story is totally different from the one you made in the makeStory: method. You should add a StoryLine Property to DisplayStoryViewController.h, and set that after you init your displayStoryController.

Answer (score 0):

make the intended variable a property type at .h file, so the other file can access it